# how to show data in view whiles using arraylist as model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Action like this :
I had to send data through different list in an arraylist
but whatever I did I couldn`t show the data correctly in the view

```
public ActionResult StudentMainPage(string name)
    {
        ViewBag.studentName = name;
        string[] fullName = name.Split(' ');
        string firstName = fullName[0];
        string lastname = fullName[1];
        List<string> CoursesName = new List<string>();
        List<string> teachersName = new List<string>();
        List<string> daysList = new List<string>();
        List<int?> classnumberList = new List<int?>();

        Guid studentId =
            db.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName == firstName && s.StudentLastName == lastname)
                .Select(s => s.Student_Id)
                .First();
        var relatedInfo = db.USP_GetClassInfoFroStudent(studentId).ToList();
        foreach (var item in relatedInfo)
        {
            CoursesName.Add(db.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseId == item.CourseId).Select(c => c.CourseName).First());
            teachersName.Add(db.Teachers.Where(t => t.Teacher_id == item.Teacher_Id)
                .Select(t => t.TeacherLastName)
                .First());
            daysList.Add(
                db.ClassMembers.Where(s => s.DaysInweek == item.DaysInweek).Select(d => d.DaysInweek).First());
            classnumberList.Add(
                db.ClassMembers.Where(n => n.classNumber == item.classNumber).Select(n => n.classNumber).First());
        }
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        data.Add(CoursesName);
        data.Add(teachersName);
        data.Add(daysList);
        data.Add(classnumberList);

        return View(data);
```

this is my view :

```
@using System.Collections
@model ArrayList
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>StudentMainPage</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <Td id="name_">@ViewBag.studentName</Td>
            <td>Welcome</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var items in Model as ArrayList)
            {
                List<string> courseName = Model[0] as List<string>;
                List<string> teachersName = Model[1] as List<string>;
                List<string> daysList = Model[2] as List<string>;
                List<int?> classnumeber = Model[3] as List<int?>;
                foreach (var course in courseName)
                {
                    <td>@courseName</td>
                }
                foreach (var tName in teachersName)
                {
                    <td>@tName</td>
                }
                foreach (var lstdays in daysList)
                {
                    <td>@lstdays</td>
                }
                foreach (var classNo in classnumeber)
                {
                    <td>@classNo</td>
                }
            }

        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is like this and only for the 1 record from the database :

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]    Akasheh  1 sunday
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]    Akasheh 1 sunday
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]    Akasheh sunday
```

Comment: Because it should be `<td>@course</td>` (not `@courseName`). But this is an awful solution. Create a view model to represent what you want in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should correct you outer `for loop`

```
@foreach (var items in Model as ArrayList)
```

When you are looping through each element in the a`ArrayList` model there is no point of accessing it's item again using indexes, As it will repeat all 4 times.

```
List<string> courseName = Model[0] as List<string>;
List<string> teachersName = Model[1] as List<string>;
List<string> daysList = Model[2] as List<string>;
List<int?> classnumeber = Model[3] as List<int?>;
```

I'd suggest removing the outer `for loop`.

Comment: razor would not let you do that. defining variables in view like that is imposible